# Prove that $A^{-1}=A^n$ if $A^n+A^{n-1}+...+A+E=O,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $A$ is regular matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I took the example of $2\times 2$ matrix
$$    \begin{bmatrix}
        x & y \\
        u & v \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
which gives matrix equation:
$$A^2+A+E=O$$
After addition, I get system of equations which I don't know how to solve:
    \begin{matrix}
        x^2+uy+x+1=0 \\
        xy+yv+y=0\\
        ux+vy+u=0\\
        uy+v^2+v+1=0\end{matrix}
Is there some other approach to prove that $A^{-1}=A^n$ rather than this?

Comment: Multiply each side of $A^n+A^{n-1}+...+E=O$ by $E - A^{-1}$.

Comment: @Dylan Provided you showed before that A is invertible.

Comment: Of course. So it is probably better to multiply by $A-I$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I guess that your $E$ is the matrix identity that I note $I$.

Multiply $A^n +A^{n-1}+ \dots + I= 0$ by $I-A$.

You get $I-A^{n+1}=0$. Therefore the minimal polynomial of your matrix divides the polynomial $P(X)=X^{n+1}-1=0$. As $0$ is not a root of $P$, $A$ is invertible. Now you can speak of $A^{-1}$!
Multiplying $I-A^{n+1}=0$ by $A^{-1}$ you get the expected result.

PS: a simple way to see that $A$ is invertible is to notice that if $A.x=0$ then $(I-A^{n+1}).x=x-A^{n+1}.x=x=0$. Hence $\ker A=0$ and $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Is it some basic idea to multiply by $I-A$ or it is a shortcut?

Comment: Yes. It is coming from the way to compute the sum of a geometric sequence.

Comment: From $I-A^{n+1}=0$ it follows trivially that $A$ is invertible, because then $A\cdot A^n = A^n\cdot A = I$, so that $A^n = A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

you have $$A^2  + A + I = 0 \to -A^2 - A = I \to A(-A-I) = I $$  therefore $$A^{-1} = -A - I. $$